# JS or JQuery: реализация блока с фоном, двигающимся за курсором

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Всем привет. Возник такой вопрос: нужно реализовать блок, пусть будет размер 500px X 500px. У блока установлен background, размером 1000px X 500px, в позиции y:0, x:0. И когда наводишь курсор на блок, что бы бэкграунд следовал на курсором (в пределах блока, без ухода за край). Т.е. двигаю курсор внутри блока вниз - позиция Y background меняется. Все это должно быть не плавно, т.е. без заданной скорости анимации. Подскажите, как сделать)
P.S. Пример такого слайдера можно найти на сайте http://apb.4game.ru/ , пролистав немного вниз.

Answer (score 1):

Ну как-то так:

```
$('.item').mousemove(function(e){

    var $this = $(this),
        relativeX = e.pageX,
        relativeY = e.pageY,
        pos = relativeX + 'px ' + relativeY + 'px ';

    $this.css('background-position', pos);

}).mouseleave(function(){

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('background-position', '0px 0px');

}).click(function(){

    // buy it!!!

});
```

Фиддл тут: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/Mv86z/